# Building a test support artifact with dependencies

Tags: dependencies, gradle

I've got a situation where my source has both tests and some test support code, along with the usual source code. I want to be able to publish both the source and the test support as separate artifacts (each with its own set of dependencies), but obviously not the test classes.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
src/main/...
src/test/...
src/testsupport/...
```

I have some dependencies defined, as per usual:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'
    ... more compile dependencies...
    testCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    ... more testCompile dependencies...
}
```

I also need the test support sourceSet:

```
sourceSets {
    testSupport {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/testsupport/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/testsupport/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

I have to add the test classpaths to the testSupport ones because the testsupport code has the same dependencies.

Finally, to create my artifact, I have:

```
task createTestSupportArtifact (type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'testsupport'
    from sourceSets.testSupport.output
}

artifacts {
    archives file: createTestSupportArtifact.archivePath, builtBy: createTestSupportArtifact
}
```

However, in my other repository that depends on these artifacts, it's not pulling in any dependencies for the testsupport artifact. I have a few theories as to why (it doesn't have it's own POM or it doesn't know the scope is test at runtime), but nothing concrete.

Is there a better approach to this? Perhaps using `configurations` intelligently?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want to use `extendsFrom` on the testSupport configurations. I didn't create a set of test projects, but it makes logical sense that if your code is working but your deps are not then you have a problem with configurations, not with sourceSets.

When you declare a new sourceSet you automatically get two new configurations based on the configuration name, in your case: `testSupportCompile` and `testSupportRuntime`. Try the following to link your normal test deps with your testSupport deps.

```
configurations {
    testSupportCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    testSupportRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

Gradle definitely uses configurations when publishing, and I would guess that since you don't explicitly add anything to your testSupportXYZ configurations it decides there are no dependencies to resolve when you later want your support artifact. The above code should link your deps the same way you linked your source and hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks; good to know about extendsFrom (side note: syntax is off... need {} around the extendsFrom portion). However, it still didn't solve the issue. I think I may have to publish artifacts with different artifactId's instead of differentiating them only be the classifier.

Comment: Oops. I think it is actually missing '.' The {} presumably work as well - as you have no reason to lie :P - but extendsFrom is just a method so '.' is more succinct.